# php multidimensional array loop optimization

Tags: php, loops, optimization, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an multidimensional array.

```
$count = count($main_array); // 6000+
```

Each element inside the main array has about 25 keys

```
$count_sub_array = count($main_array[0]); // 25
```

I have about 3000 unique value for one of the key. i.e.

```
for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++){
    if($main_array[$i][$match]){
         array_push($unique_array,$main_array[$i][$match]);
    }
}
$unique_array = array_unique($unique_array); // count - 3000
```

I would like to iterate through each element in the array and group them by unique type. And also I wish to group the elements as per one of the specific index for instance

```
$unique_index = array('2012-08','2012-07','2012-06','2012-05','2012-04','2012-03','2012-02', '2012-01');
```

#count of unique index at present is 13

so that result looks like:

```
array (size=2689)
 0 => 
array (size=5)
  'type' => string 'abc' (length=19)
  'totalCost' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => float 790.08
      '2012-08-01' => float 1501.84
      '2012-09-01' => float 1568.9
      '2012-10-01' => float 2756.04
      '2012-11-01' => float 2428.42
      '2012-12-01' => float 1901.09
      '2013-01-01' => float 2538.59
      '2013-02-01' => float 1537.57
      '2013-03-01' => float 1674.51
      '2013-04-01' => float 1141.01
      '2013-05-01' => float 764.24
      '2013-06-01' => float 1179.84
      '2013-07-01' => float 1252.66
   'numOrders' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => int 16
      '2012-08-01' => int 66
      '2012-09-01' => int 65
      '2012-10-01' => int 59
      '2012-11-01' => int 60
      '2012-12-01' => int 47
      '2013-01-01' => int 85
      '2013-02-01' => int 50
      '2013-03-01' => int 46
      '2013-04-01' => int 41
      '2013-05-01' => int 22
      '2013-06-01' => int 32
      '2013-07-01' => int 47
  'TotalRevenue' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => float 1695.99
      '2012-08-01' => float 7418.17
      '2012-09-01' => float 7827.99
      '2012-10-01' => float 7929.63
      '2012-11-01' => float 4815.74
      '2012-12-01' => float 5592.59
      '2013-01-01' => float 6874.02
      '2013-02-01' => float 11599.49
      '2013-03-01' => float 10358.57
      '2013-04-01' => float 6909.55
      '2013-05-01' => float 6983.38
      '2013-06-01' => float 7211.84
      '2013-07-01' => float 10422.59
  'profit' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => float 905.91
      '2012-08-01' => float 5916.33
      '2012-09-01' => float 6259.09
      '2012-10-01' => float 5173.59
      '2012-11-01' => float 2387.32
      '2012-12-01' => float 3691.5
      '2013-01-01' => float 4335.43
      '2013-02-01' => float 10061.92
      '2013-03-01' => float 8684.06
      '2013-04-01' => float 5768.54
      '2013-05-01' => float 6219.14
      '2013-06-01' => float 6032
      '2013-07-01' => float 9169.93
1 => 
array (size=5)
  'type' => string 'bcd' (length=26)
  'totalCost' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => float 599.53
      '2012-08-01' => float 419.18
      '2012-09-01' => float 212.63
      '2012-10-01' => float 462.55
      '2012-11-01' => float 450.08
      '2012-12-01' => float 447.1
      '2013-01-01' => float 657
      '2013-02-01' => float 734.68
      '2013-03-01' => float 1006.91
      '2013-04-01' => float 1497.95
      '2013-05-01' => float 2100.96
      '2013-06-01' => float 3845.33
      '2013-07-01' => float 6817.38
  'numOrders' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => int 11
      '2012-08-01' => int 33
      '2012-09-01' => int 25
      '2012-10-01' => int 28
      '2012-11-01' => int 33
      '2012-12-01' => int 28
      '2013-01-01' => int 33
      '2013-02-01' => int 45
      '2013-03-01' => int 54
      '2013-04-01' => int 53
      '2013-05-01' => int 69
      '2013-06-01' => int 91
      '2013-07-01' => int 180
  'TotalRevenue' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => float 1201.32
      '2012-08-01' => float 4889.65
      '2012-09-01' => float 2171.5
      '2012-10-01' => float 2573.75
      '2012-11-01' => float 2375.1
      '2012-12-01' => float 2807.28
      '2013-01-01' => float 2933.05
      '2013-02-01' => float 5534.61
      '2013-03-01' => float 6946.02
      '2013-04-01' => float 8555.78
      '2013-05-01' => float 8202.32
      '2013-06-01' => float 14140.04
      '2013-07-01' => float 22043.54
  'profit' => 
    array (size=13)
      '2012-07-01' => float 601.79
      '2012-08-01' => float 4470.47
      '2012-09-01' => float 1958.87
      '2012-10-01' => float 2111.2
      '2012-11-01' => float 1925.02
      '2012-12-01' => float 2360.18
      '2013-01-01' => float 2276.05
      '2013-02-01' => float 4799.93
      '2013-03-01' => float 5939.11
      '2013-04-01' => float 7057.83
      '2013-05-01' => float 6101.36
      '2013-06-01' => float 10294.71
      '2013-07-01' => float 15226.16
 );
```

How can I optimize the loop?

At present i have the following logic:

```
 1. get the main array from mysql
 2. get unique elements
 3. foreach unique element
       a. foreach key like '2013-06-01', '2013-07-01'
       b. foreach main array
              match above key i.e. if($time == '2013-06-01')
       c. get $value['totalCost'], $value['numOrders'], $value['profit'], value['revenue']
```

As per me, complexity of this loop is: 3000 * 13 * 6000;

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You mention that this data is coming from SQL, have you tried doing some of the grouping and processing in your database query?

Comment: Yes, its already grouped that's why I had to get unique array to form array in the above structure.

Comment: After spending long time looking at your example i am still not sure what your initial data (in database) looks like. If i knew that, or at least have a better example of what your result set (initial array) looks like, i believe i could write a sql query that will allow writing your output array in one loop with one conditional witin that loop. Because you don't need steps 2 and 3a at all and the whole 3 is just one time 3.b but with smarter match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop 3 times anyway, but choose well your loops.

Since the main array is the largest, you want to loop only once. Instead of build the dates array first, you build and fill it as you loop througth the main array.

1. get the main array from mysql
2. loop only once

   ```
   $dates = array();
   $measures = array(
       'totalCost'    => 0,
       'numOrders'    => 0,
       'TotalRevenue' => 0,
       'profit'       => 0
   );
   foreach ($main as $main_element) {
       foreach (array_keys($measures) as $measure) {
           foreach ($main_element[$measure] as $date => $value) {
               if(!isset($dates[$date])) {
                   $dates[$date] = $measures;
               }
               $dates[$date][$measure] += $value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Note: Depending of your preferences for the structure of the result, you could replace

```
$dates[$date][$measure]
```

by

```
$dates[$measure][$date]
```

You still have 3 loops, but you loop only
6000 * 4 * 13 times, which is much better.

Comment: Thanks. but that does not mean, I have a unique array. Since 6000 iteration is the main loop.. and 3000 are unique solution. now I need to group unique elements in the said fashion.. which means.. 3000 times I need to find for every date and measure combination value from the main array else assign a 0 as the value

Comment: That's what I'm doing.

Can you please give me the structure of the result array? This will help me to understand in what point my solution is no sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I have optimized the complete process using memcache. I will post a sample array for you soon. Bear with me until then.

Comment: I updated the code to initalize each date and measure combination and assign it 0 if no value is found in the main array.

Answer (score 0):

I used memcached php extension to solve the issue. With the result first time it takes usual time however later it executes faster once the cache key is found on the memcached server.